# How to run setup and tear down function for all the tests in sub directories in py.test?

Tags: python, pytest

I have unit tests that runs with py.test for python 2.7 and py.test 3.0. My test directory is like this:

```
tests
---dir1
   test1.py
-------sub-dir1-1
       test-1-1.py
-------sub-dir1-2
       test-1-2.py
---dir2
   test2.py
-------sub-dir2-1
       test-2-1.py
-------sub-dir2-2
       test-2-2.py
```

I want all my tests to run a common setup and tear down function before and after test. I would like to do it with the least modification of all the test code.

Thanks

Comment: have a base test class that al test inherit from with your setup and teardown defined there?

Comment: I have a lot of test classes like more than 2000, so I am trying not to change all of them if it is possible.

Comment: in this case you could probably try and run-time patch the TestCase itself, assuming your test inherit from that, but that is a dirty hack

Comment: otherwise just sed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can write a fixture that is session scoped (`scope` param) and make it used automatically (`autouse` param). I used a "yield fixture" as an example. Please note, that `pytest.yield_fixture` is deprecated since pytest 3.0 and `pytest.fixture` allows use of `yield`.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def callattr_ahead_of_alltests(request):
    print 'run_pre_start'
    yield
    print 'run_after_finish'
```

It will run before first test (printing "run_pre_start") and part after `yield` will run after all the tests (printing "run_after_finish").

Comment: where this code lives? Does py.test scan all the test code and auto detect this?

Comment: You should put it inside `conftest.py` in your "tests" dir. More info about storing fixtures in the [documentation](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#sharing-a-fixture-across-tests-in-a-module-or-class-session)